# Error in installation hhvm with debian 7.8

Tags: debian, hhvm

When I make `apt-get install hhvm` in prompt console a have a mistake

```
 Aucune version du paquet hhvm n'est disponible, mais il existe dans la base de données. Cela signifie en général que le paquet est manquant, qu'il est devenu obsolète ou qu'il n'est disponible que sur une autre source
```

How I can resolve this problem

Comment: This appears to be a [package management issue](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Aucune%20version%20du%20paquet%20hhvm%20n%27est%20disponible%2C%20mais%20il%20existe%20dans%20la%20base%20de%20donn%C3%A9es.%20Cela%20signifie%20en%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral%20que%20le%20paquet%20est%20manquant%2C%20qu%27il%20est%20devenu%20obsol%C3%A8te%20ou%20qu%27il%20n%27est%20disponible%20que%20sur%20une%20autre%20source) rather than a programming one. It's probably more suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) or [the UNIX SE site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 0):

We need debian 64 bits version to install HHVM.

You may have tried to install HHVM with debian 32 bits, apt-get do not find any corresponding version and you got this error.